# How to draw in canvas 2D this shape and fill it with color?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

[image: canvas 2D]

This should be **without this diagonal**. I want to draw two arcs one with x2 smaller radius, join them and `fill()`. I know how to calculate the end and beginning of an arc, problem is arcs are always drawn clockwise, so to draw second arc within same `ctx.beginPath()` I have to use something like `ctx.moveTo()` but problem with moveTo is I get two different paths as proof `closePath()` cause this diagonal.

So I want to know **how to draw arc in other direction than clockwise or how to use moveTo() but still beeing able to fill this shape**. Filling now cause following issue:
[image]
White diagonal visible.

Comment: could you share a snippet of what you've accomplished so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arcs are not always drawn clockwise.    The [sixth parameter to `.arc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) is a boolean which when true will make the arc be drawn anti-clockwise.

However you will also need to reverse the start and end angles, otherwise the arc will attempt to go the long way around:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(20, 20, 40, 30 * Math.PI / 180, 80 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.arc(20, 20, 150, 80 * Math.PI / 180, 30 * Math.PI / 180, true);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = '#e0e0ff';
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: This is it, only start and end angle switch places because it's anti-clockwise. Thanks!

Comment: Even nicer solution than mine - I was calculating beginning and the end of arcs and then using lineTo().

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [`lineWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth) property to make the arc thicker. In this case you'll only need one call to `arc`:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    
context.beginPath();
context.arc(20, 20, 40, 0, Math.PI / 4);
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Creative solution.

Comment: The `ctx.closePath` function is a path function and redundant in your example. Similar to a `ctx.lineTo` it creates a path segment from the last path point to the previous `ctx.moveTo` or first point after a `ctx.beginPath`. It is not related or needed after a `ctx.beginPath` call.